# why all data is appended to only one row instead of multiple row as shown in the figure

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

import tksheet

top = tk.Tk()

sheet = tksheet.Sheet(top)

sheet.grid()
dataList = []
bubble = 4000
pressuremin = 14.7
pressuremax = 5000
Pressureincrement = 1000
steps = (pressuremax - pressuremin) / Pressureincrement
for i in range(0, int(steps)):
    currentPressure = pressuremin
    pressureArr = []
    rsArr = []
    while currentPressure <= pressuremax:
            if currentPressure >= bubble:
                pressureArr.append(currentPressure)
                rsval = 500
                rsArr.append(rsval)
                currentPressure += Pressureincrement
            elif currentPressure < bubble:
                pressureArr.append(currentPressure)
                rsval1 = 350
                rsArr.append(rsval1)
                currentPressure += Pressureincrement
    dataList.append([pressureArr, rsArr])
    sheet.set_sheet_data(dataList)
sheet.enable_bindings(("single_select",

                       "row_select",

                       "column_width_resize",

                       "arrowkeys",

                       "right_click_popup_menu",

                       "rc_select",

                       "rc_insert_row",

                       "rc_delete_row",

                       "copy",

                       "cut",

                       "paste",

                       "delete",

                       "undo",

                       "edit_cell"))
top.mainloop()
```

the result of this code as shown in the following figure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwUh7.png)
I want the result be table with multiple row like
row    col 1    col 2
1- 14.7         350
2-1014.7        350
3-2014.7        350
4-3014.7        350
5-4014.7        500

Answer (score 0):

You created the `dataList` in a wrong way. It can be simplified just using the while loop (without the for loop):

```py
dataList = []
bubble = 4000
pressuremin = 14.7
pressuremax = 5000
Pressureincrement = 1000
currentPressure = pressuremin
while currentPressure <= pressuremax:
    rsval = 500 if currentPressure >= bubble else 350
    dataList.append([currentPressure, rsval])
    currentPressure += Pressureincrement
sheet.set_sheet_data(dataList)
```

The result:

[image]